# Count how many depending on foreign key status

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables - info, article and authors

INFO  has

```
\----+-----------+------------+  
| ID |  AuthorID |  ArticleID |  
+----+-----------+------------+  
| 1  |  1        |    1       |  
| 2  |  2        |    2       |    
| 3  |  3        |    NULL    |  
| 4  |  1        |    3       |
```

Article

```
\----+------------+   
| ID |  Status    |   
+----+------------+   
| 1  |  Confirmed |  
| 2  |  Pending   |    
| 3  |  Reviewing |
```

Authors

```
\----+----------+
| ID |  Status  |
+----+----------+
| 1  |  John    |  
| 2  |  Mark    |  
| 3  |  Peter   |
```

I want to count how many "confirmed" and how many "non-confirmed" articles every author has.  "non-confirmed" articles include everything that doesn't have status "confirmed" or is NULL in the INFO TABLE.

For this little example answer should be:

```
\--------+-----------+---------------+
| AUTHOR | CONFIRMED | NON-CONFIRMED |
+--------+-----------+---------------+
| John   | 1         | 1             |
| Mark   | 0         | 1             |
| Peter  | 0         | 1             |
```

Comment: Hint: JOINs, GROUP BY, COUNT. etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.  I used temp tables for myself when recreating the data set.  Replace with your table names.

```
select  c.status , sum(case when  b.status ='confirmed' then 1 else 0 end)Confirmed, sum(case when  b.status ='confirmed' then 0 else 1 end)NonConfirmed
from  #info a left join #article b on a.articleid=b.id 
left join #authors c on a.authorid=c.id 
group by  c.status
```